# execute function in different shell

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I usually `zsh`. I want to execute a function in bash and return back to my original shell. I can do this manually, but I want to automate it. How can I do that?

For example, I am on zsh.
I want to execute `func`, which is a `function()` in  `bigscript.sh` file. I am sourcing the `bigscript.sh` file in my `.zshrc`
I tried adding shebang `!#/bin/bash` in the `bigscript.sh` file, but that does not change the shell.
I tried another approach of putting `function` in a standalone `function.sh` file and added shebang to it. It worked. However, I do not want to break the files into smaller `.sh` files.

So, any suggestions on changing the shell for a single function..?

Comment: The fact that you have a function is somewhat irrelevant; to execute code in another shell, you have to start that shell's interpreter, at which point you can execute any arbitrary script you want. Defining the function in your current `zsh` session doesn't make a difference; the function has to be defined in the new shell's session before it can be executed.

Comment: Thats what I want. When I call the function, I want it to change the shell and execute itself on the new shell...

Comment: Why not just write the function in `zsh` in the first place?

Comment: @chepner Its legacy code. Most of the devs are using bash, and few are using zsh. I get what you are saying.. create a wrapper function or ultimately break the script into smaller scripts. But I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: Let me put it this way: what function do you have that you can *define* in `zsh` but doesn't actually *run* in `zsh`, necessitating you start a `bash` instance to run it?

Comment: Basically(!), a function written in bash, should run in zsh as well. Is that function using any features which are very bash specific? If not, `source file_with_function.sh` would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If the function is written in bash, you can not - in general - execute it from Zsh, since bash and Zsh are different languages. Of course since there are some similarities, it is possible to write functions which work the same on bash on Zsh, I wouldn't rely on it. Even if your function happens to be a "compatible" one at the moment, if someone modifies this function later, he possibly won't be aware that this function will be used outside of the bash context and change it in a way so that it doesn't run or - even worse - behaves differently under Zsh.

So the only way would be to write an interface bash script, which sources the file where this function is defined, and executes it - something like

```
#!/bin/bash
# Interface script to call bash function foo from other languages
. file-which-defines-function-foo
foo "$@"
```